# VBScript return a value in a string using specific location and unknown lengh of value

Tags: string, vbscript, return-value

I have a problem that I believe may be fairly simple for you to solve for you experienced VBScripters.

Currently I have a String of: "12 January 2012"

This String changes depending on XML due to being a derived item.

Now I need to retrieve only the month as I'll be comparing it with another value later on in my program. The problem I have is that I do not know how to retrieve the month due to the value being different, so for example it could be "11 March 2013".

Now I think I know how I can do this, by searching 3 charcters inwards from the left and 5 from the right and then assign that value to a variable.

Problem is I'm new to this and although I think I have the solution I do not have the knowledge to get it working!

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

```
datestring = "12 January 2012"
WScript.Echo Split(datestring)(1)
```